# Не могу понять, как остановить выполнение методов после метода c return С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть код метода `buttonAdd_Click`, и если `if` писать не в виде отдельного метода `return` работает и дальнейшие проверки методов не идут, но если вынести код проверки `if` в метод `return` не сработает, вопрос почему и как сделать правильно?

```
    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckOverflow();

        if (textBoxName.TextLength < 1 || textBoxYear.TextLength < 1 || textBoxPrice.TextLength < 1 || textBoxWeight.TextLength < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Заполните TextBox");
            return;
        }
        DataTransfer();
        ClearTextBox();
     }
```

Comment: Ну например возвращайте из нового метода bool, и в зависимости от значения делайте или нет return в основном методе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через возврат bool, как в комментах написано, но можно бросить исключение. Здесь же работа с ошибками, верно?

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CheckOverflow();
        EnsureTextBoxLength();
        DataTransfer();
        ClearTextBox();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void EnsureTextBoxLength()
{
    if (textBoxName.TextLength == 0
        || textBoxYear.TextLength == 0
        || textBoxPrice.TextLength == 0
        || textBoxWeight.TextLength == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Заполните TextBox");
    }
}
```

При возникновении исключения код не продолжает выполняться, а происходит переход в блок `catch`.

Но если действовать грамотно, то надо реализовать [валидацию данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/winforms/user-input-validation-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).